# NetBeans (Java Swing): Set window size

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

This is driving me crazy. When I set an appropriate size for my window in design-mode it just ignores this size and uses something else when I compile and run. Even tough I set the minimumSize and preferredSize it just ignores this... Why? How can I set my own size?

Comment: Are you doing this by dragging with the mouse or are you setting a property?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even if you've set the size with `minimumSize` and `preferredSize`, you might have forgotten to call [`Window.pack()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) in which Swing will resize the components (and all of it's subcomponents) according to the sizes set.

You call it in your window (or whatever is building your window) after all the preferred sizes are set.

Alternatively you can use the [`Component.setSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setSize%28int,%20int%29) method but it [comes with some caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384702/setsize-v-s-setpreferredsize-and-pack).

Comment: Could you please explain where this call to pack() must bo done ?

Comment: Sure, `pack()` should be called after all your layout (setting layouts, sizes and positions) of your UI component is done. It depends on where your code for layouting is (usually in the constructor).

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if you really set the size of the JFrame or of a contained JPanel?

Have you tried `setSize`?

Answer (score 0):

I've found myself in a similar situation while using netbeans ide. I had a read of the following thread, that helped:

http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic28011.html

Seems as though the swing application framework is saving the app's window size in a subfolder within your home dir (for Windows, the "Application Data" folder, for Linux, in your "~/" home folder).

For example, for my application 'CrapApp', swing had saved some last-window-size info into the sub-folder "~/.CrapApp/", into a file called "mainFrame.session.xml".

So no matter how I re-sized the window within the designer, upon running, it seemed to have ignored it and instead loaded the window size from the preferences within this sub-folder.

So my solution was to delete this preserved-settings sub-folder, eg, in my case, "rm -rf ~/.CrapApp/"

Then the problem went away and I could re-size within the designer and run the app with this re-sized window now visible.

This made me want to learn what triggered this issue. I noticed that simply running the app within the netbeans ide and closing it didn't generate the sub-folder.

After a bit of tinkering with my app, I noticed the following action triggered the generation of this "~/.CrapApp/" sub-folder.

1. Going to my app's "Help >> About"
2. Click the "Close" button in the about dialog that appears
3. Exit the app

And now the "~/.CrapApp/" sub-folder re-appears. This help/about dialog was auto-generated by netbeans ide, so I didn't really tinker with it, but this seems to have been the culprit in my case.

Perhaps it may be a bug in the netbeans ide, I'm using a somewhat old version (v6.8), which seems roughly from the era of your original post too.