# setSize() v/s setPreferredSize() and pack()

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am not clear about what is the difference between `setSize()` and `setPreferredSize()`.
what would happen if i use `setSize()` instead of `setPreferredSize()`.

---

And what exactly does `pack()` method do ?

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783793/java-difference-between-the-setpreferredsize-and-setsize-methods-in-componen)

Comment: The answer is related to what layout manager you are using. Some don't care about `setSize()`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Calling `pack()` on a window will size it based on the preferredSize of its containing components. It will be as small as possible but taking into account the preferredSize and layout of its components.
If you just randomly use `frame.setSize()`, then the components added to the content pane will expand/contract to fit the space available, which means the preferred size of each component may be overridden.

`setSize()` sets the size of the component and `setPreferredSize` sets the preferred size.The Layoutmanager will try to arrange that much space for your component.
It depends on whether you're using a layout manager or not ...

See [Java: Difference between the setPreferredSize() and setSize() methods in components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783793/java-difference-between-the-setpreferredsize-and-setsize-methods-in-componen)