# Java Swing Program Execution Error

Tags: java, swing, jframe

In java, I made a registration form using swing, the program gets compiled but when I run it no new window opens with the registration form that i created. And in command prompt also the cursor goes to the next command line as if the program has been executed and form window closed by the user.
the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class M {

    JFrame f;
    JPanel p;
    JButton b1, b2;
    TextField t;
    JLabel l1, l2;

    M() {
        f = new JFrame("FIRST");
        p = new JPanel();
        f.getContentPane().add(p);
        p.setVisible(true);
        b1 = new JButton("Save");
        b1.setBounds(10, 10, 10, 10);
        p.add(b1);
        b2 = new JButton("Exit");
        b2.setBounds(25, 10, 10, 10);
        p.add(b2);
    }

    public static void main(String arr[]) {
        M m1 = new M();
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code and what you have tried. there is not enough info given in your question.

Comment: Did you have a question? Recommended reading: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: @user3779954 can we get a code snippet. A common cause of this is not setting frame.setVisible(true);

Comment: okay. i just uploaded the code. Its just the starting part.

Comment: No. Edit your post to include the relevant information. Make sure it's properly formatted.

Comment: sorry understood.. it should be. f.setVisible(true).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the JFrame to visible ,not the JPanel.

In your case f , not p.

Answer (score 1):

Set the frame to Visible

```
f.setVisible(true);
```

Also to set the size correctly use

```
f.pack();
```

Comment: whats the difference between f.setsize() and f.pack()?

Comment: @Crate Check out this related question for the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384702/setsize-v-s-setpreferredsize-and-pack