# How to hide components of a JFrame on initialization + Netbeans design view: color display

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, initialization, hide

I'm using the design view of Netbeans to create a UI for my Java App.
For my login window I want the label "Wrong username..." to show up ONLY if the login wasn't successful.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        if(!tryLogin()) jLabel3.setVisible(true);
}
```

So what's a best-practice to hide the label at the beginning?

Where should I put `jLabel3.setVisible(false);`?

And since this is probably an extremely easy question I got one more problem:

I set the background color of my JFrame to a different one that is displayed in the Netbeans design view. What can I do for it to display all my color changes immediatly?
I saw a possible answer here: [Netbeans GUI preview is different from Runtime view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455840/netbeans-gui-preview-is-different-from-runtime-view) but I cannot find "%APPDATA%\CompanyName\myApp\mainFrame.session.xml" to test it and not sure if it will solve my problem.

Here are the pics of the UI in design view and when it's actually running:[image][image]

if you need more information just let me know!

any other tips for UI making are greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Set `jLabel3.setVisible(false);` in the constructor.
- set your button opaque, using jbutton.setOpaque(true) or from Netbeans properties tab select the checkbox against the property "Opaque".