# Netbeans designer shows different form than when the program runs

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, designer

In netbeans designer it looks like this:
[image]

When I run the application it looks like this:
[image]

I am using cardLayout as main layout and cards use free design layout, there are multile cards but all of them are the same size like the first screenshot.

Comment: Some men may say that using NetBeans is a mistake. Those men are right

Comment: @akalikin What should I use then?

Comment: people use Eclipse, but I highly recommend Jetbrains IntelliJ. Most of their IDE's are brilliant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of Nimbus look and feel is default for swing application.

For reference link to Oracle docs.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html

The "look" of an application refers to its appearance. The "feel" refers to how the widgets behave.

Editing here since I don't have enough reputation to add a comment.

Refer:
[NetBeans (Java Swing): Set window size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933016/netbeans-java-swing-set-window-size)

Accepted Answer:

Even if you've set the size with minimumSize and preferredSize, you might have forgotten to call Window.pack() in which Swing will resize the components (and all of it's subcomponents) according to the sizes set.

You call it in your window (or whatever is building your window) after all the preferred sizes are set.

Comment: Nimbus look and feel is perfectly fine, the problem is the giant space at the bottom.

Comment: This is side effects of drag and drop. Provide code which is generated by neat-beans.

Comment: So this was actually caused by Nimbus look and feel because there was a card with a lot of textfields and those textfields are much bigger in Nimbus than in Windows, when I set the look and feel to Windows, the running program looked excatly same as in the designer (without the large space). Thank you.